# jQuery active class on navigation links not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, scroll

I have searched through similar questions, and feel like I've tried just about everything to no avail.

I want a class ".active" to append to a link in my page's navigation when a user scrolls to the corresponding section of my one-page site. When the user continues to scroll, that active class will disappear from the link and become added to the next link.

The jQuery for the scrolling does work in the code, but nothing else seems to.

Here is my site: http://tendigi.com/staging/

And here are (shortened) the sections of code:

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#team">TEAM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#process">PROCESS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#brands">BRANDS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#press">PRESS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="#meetup">MEETUP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>

<section>
    <a id="about">Header</a>
Some Text
</section>
<section>
    <a id="team">Header</a>
Some Text
</section>
<section>
    <a id="portfolio">Header</a>
Some Text
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
topMenu = $("#nav"),
topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+75,
// All list items
menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
// Anchors corresponding to menu items
scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
  var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
  if (item.length) { return item; }
}),
noScrollAction = false;

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
var href = $(this).attr("href"),
    offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
noScrollAction = true;
$('html, body').stop().animate({ 
    scrollTop: offsetTop
},{
    duration: 300,
    complete: function() {
        menuItems
            .parent().removeClass("active")
            .end().filter("[href=" + href +"]").parent().addClass("active");
        setTimeout(function(){ noScrollAction = false; }, 10);
    }
});
e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
if(!noScrollAction){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }
   }    
});​
```

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so I apologize if I'm not doing this correctly! And help would be SO APPRECIATED.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see this is working. The active link is being applied to the `<li />` though. If you need it on the `<a />` change this:

```
.end().filter("[href=" + href +"]").parent().addClass("active");
```

to:

```
.end().filter("[href=" + href +"]").addClass("active");
```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**

whoops! you need to change the line before as well. So it's:

```
.parent().removeClass("active")
.end().filter("[href=" + href +"]").parent().addClass("active");
```

to:

```
.removeClass("active")
.filter("[href=" + href +"]").addClass("active");
```

---

You also look like you need to tweak your threshold by 5 or 6 pixels...